# How to export an interactive image created in R in PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, interactive

I would like to know a way to create the interactive image in R and convert it to PDF so that from the PDF I can manipulate it, that is, it remains interactive. I created an interactive image in R but when I save it it becomes static, I tried to make it in RMarkdown but it only allows me to convert it to html. Help me please.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755770/save-interactive-plotly-in-pdf-or-eps-in-r/73764105#73764105